# How can I connect to snowflake in aws lambda function without using snowflake-connector-python?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to be able to connect to snowflake using the `snowflake-connector-python` package but it is too large when it is packaged up.  The maximum unzipped size for lambda's is 250 MB and just installing `snowflake-connector-python` (latest version) brings in `pyarrow` and `numpy` which are very large.  The deployment package unzipped is 324 MB.  What other options do I have?

**UPDATE:**

I have moved to version 1.9.0 and am receiving multiple errors.  It looks like the following thread has the same issue.
https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009bTn7ASAS/cant-establish-a-connection-using-snowflakeconnectorpython-v19?t=1570467024620&searchQuery=#

**UPDATE:**

Moving to version 1.9.0 with `asn1crypto<1.0.0` (0.24.0) worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are aware if this issue and our engineers are actively looking at this. The current recommended workaround is for you use use version 1.9.0 instead of version 2.0. This should bring the size back down to a size acceptable for lambda deployment.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you Hilda, that's very helpful.  Do you know what version of snowflake-sqlalchemy will be compatible with snowflake-connector-python 1.9.0?

Comment: It would be great if there was an official snowflake AWS lamba layer that gave access to the snowflake-connector-python[pandas]

Comment: Hi Hilda, I got the same issue. I need using **Pandas DataFrames with the Python Connector**, it requires **Snowflake Connector >= 2.1.2 and PyArrow = 0.17.0**. I can't deploy it to Lambda because it exceeded 250 MB. Would you please help me in this case?

Comment: Seems like there isn't a way to deploy the snowflake connector with pandas to Lambda at the moment, is that fair to say?

Comment: Could not find any alternative , not fixed yet